# Ubuntu's messed up menu bar?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, appmenu

I am on Xenial Proposed and take updates daily. After yesterday's update this is the weird thing happening.

First, the menu bar for the current window is not appearing. For any app, it shows the menu bar of the window behind it. In the following screenshot, I should be seeing the menu for Terminal and not Chrome.

[image]

If I click on the (x), Chrome shuts down and I see terminal without any menu! Here's the `lsb_release` info.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Could it be nVidia related as well? That got updated too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself by installing [Compiz configuration settings manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) and following the steps below.

- Choose **Window Management** from the left panel.
- Click on **Place Windows**.
- Make sure **Placement Mode** is **Smart**
- Make sure the checkbox **Enable Place Windows** under **Use This Plugin** is checked.